# Validate field is unique compared to another field in same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I have two fields in a `new` or `edit` form:

```
<%= f.text_field :email %>
<%= f.text_field :parent_email %>
```

How, in my model, can I validate that `parent_email` is different from `email`? The `exclusion` option seems like it might work, but I can't figure out how to access the `email` field's value within the model. Do I need to implement this in the controller instead?

```
validates :parent_email, exclusion: self.email # doesn't work, nor does :email
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work (but I guess there are cooler solutions out there):

```
class User
  validate  :email_differs_from_parent_email

  private
  def email_differs_from_parent_email
    if email == parent_email
      errors.add(:parent_email, "parent_email must differ from email") 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That does it. As usual, I'm spoiled by all the automatic methods. Thank you.